# Dealing with full stop at the end of the domain www.domain.com

Tags: .net, redirect, mod-rewrite, iis

I have an issue with a website that when people type in to the address bar or link to from a document in the format www.domain.com. This produces a HTTP 400 Bad request.

Initially I thought I could just add an HTTP module that checks all requests and if the domain (www.domain.com.) ends with a full stop then redirect to it without the ending full stop.

I have also tried using IIS rewrite rules to check if the URL is either empty or has only an initial full stop.

These solutions work ok if my URL ends in a full stop but my issue is when I add the address as www.domain.com. it doesn't reach the HTTP module or even reach IIS rewrite rules.

Looking at "The resource cannot be found." error when there is a "dot" at the end of the url - Stack Overflow  gave me some other solutions which I have tried but again when its a malformed domain www.domain.com. it doesn't reach the
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e) function.

There was also an article that I read that said I could hook into an outbound rule and match a 400 header but again it doesn't reach here bore .NET decides its malformed.

There are lots of articles explaining how to get round a url that ends in a full stop but not any that has a malformed domain www.domain.com.

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` for this to work:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Without this, the module will only be run for file extensions it recognises.